# Marker-file for torque CartoDB

Tags: carto, markers, torque

I am trying to plot some color code (only 3 colors by the moment) cars in my map instead the regular color code points. I am using torque cat to do it, but all the time the car is in black!, I need some help. This is my code:

```
/** torque_cat visualization */

Map {
  -torque-frame-count:64;
  -torque-animation-duration:1;
  -torque-time-attribute:"date";
  -torque-aggregation-function:"CDB_Math_Mode(torque_category)";
  -torque-resolution:2;
  -torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}

#untitled_table_1{
  comp-op: lighter;
  marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
  marker-line-color: #FFF;
  marker-line-width: 0;
  marker-line-opacity: 1;
  marker-type: ellipse;
  marker-width: 6;
  marker-fill: #FF9900;
  marker-file: url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/nTX/AGX/nTXAGXyTB.svg);  
}

#untitled_table_1[value=1] {
  marker-fill: #B81609;
}
#untitled_table_1[value=2] {
 marker-fill: #012700;
}
#untitled_table_1[value=3] {
  marker-fill: #7B00B4;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

torque does not support marker-file and marker-fill at the same time, in other words, you can not color a sprite using marker fill.

The workaround is to have an sprite per color.