# Custom icons for Torque Categories in CartoDB

Tags: carto, cartocss

We’re developing a project with CartoDB and we want to show the elements clustering by zone and showing the most used one (Mode).

We're doing this with Torque Categories, and it works! :)

The questions is: how can I customize the icons of the markers?

I have tried with these options, and both make the icons disappear.

1. marker-file on #id[value=X]

   #mapId[value=1] {
      marker-file: url(http://domain.com/Image001.png); 
   }
2. marker-file on #id[columnName=”value”]

   #mapId[name="TEST"] {
      marker-file: url(http://domain.com/Image001.png); 
   }

I've read you cannot use marker-fill with [marker-file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137384/marker-file-for-torque-cartodb), but I've removed all marker-fill's and still don't see the images.

How can it be done?

Comment: Where I said **strong text**, I should said
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137384/marker-file-for-torque-cartodb (I haven't enough reputation to edit)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, and sorry, now I know where I can write clarifications :)

Comment: There is a issue opened in CartoDB GitHub:
https://github.com/CartoDB/torque/issues/152
Waiting for response.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you use in the question is valid: there was an issue with Torque category (as mentioned in the comments) that we solved, so it should be working at the moment.